# PHP admin / user action detection

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, job-scheduling

I have a php/codeigniter app function to implement with following scenario:

1. There are two user areas: Admin and Member area
2. A user makes an order
3. Only the "logged in" Admin user has to detect on the very submission that an order has been made. (remember no interaction by the Admin)

I thought about a cron job that checks every few minutes but there has to be another way - maybe someone can help here - thanks.

Comment: set up ajax request on timed interval to a CI controller method that checks for new orders

Comment: nice idea but that still would be somehow equivalent to a cron job. I wanted something to let the admin know that an order has been placed by the member action

Comment: if you mean inform admin by email...would have to use cron job, if you mean advise admin while online would use ajax. I assumed by `only logged in admin` you meant you want to display in page

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the above by triggering an AJAX call to a CI controller action that gets all of the orders that have been created in the last X minutes, if your user is logged in as an admin. I would make it extensible - so basically, you send a **lowerThreshold** and an **upperThreshold** timestamp, that allows you to retrieve the orders in a specific timestamp. An example of a model function would be:

```
public function retrieveBetweenThreshold($lowerThreshold, $upperThreshold) {
    $this->db->where('created_at > ', $lowerThreshold)
    $this->db->where('created_at < ', $upperThreshold)
    return $this->db->get('order')->result_array();
}
```

As an additional factor, I would implement your idea this way - try store the sign-off date of an admin when they log off (pretty straight-forward) or when they close the window (jQuery unload() method: http://api.jquery.com/unload/).

When the admin signs in, trigger an AJAX request with the current timestamp and the admin's sign-off date, so that you retrieve the number of entries that have been made while they were signed off, and then carry on with the regular AJAX call every X minutes.

**UPDATE**: For the concept of *Ajax Push*, which is what you seem to want, have a look at: http://ape-project.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still would require a triggering of time based function to check whether an order has come in. I rather thought of a way in which when the user makes the order - the logged in admin would be conveyed that an order has been placed.

Comment: @owsata Hey, updated my answer to reflect your comment. Let me know if that's what you wanted.